# How to remove a form from formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

views.py

```
formset = ComparisonScoreFormSet(initial=[
    {'comparison': comparison} for comparison in Comparison.objects.all()
])
```

I initialized a formset with initial values. This adds forms with initial values and also one form with no initial value.

I need to remove the form with no initial value.

I need to do something like the following

```
del formset[-1] #since the form with no initial value is at the last
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
formset = ComparisonScoreFormSet(
    initial=[{'comparison': comparison} for comparison in Comparison.objects.all()],
    extra = 0, # defines number of extra empty forms
)
```

Comment: Setting extra when initializing the formset did not work however,  setting it when creating formset by formset_factory did work!